# Crystal report passing parameters in subreports using dataset

Tags: vb.net

We are getting correct output for crystal report using dataset which does not have a sub report.But it does not work for subreports?
How to pass crystal report's sub reports parameter values using dataset through coding in vb.net?
We are using Msaccess as back end

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure exactly what you are asking, but here is a way of setting a creating, setting and passing params to a crystal report

Load up a standard dataset from your db.
Use the DateSet.WriteXmlSchema to create an Xml Schema.
Use the visal studio tool Xsd.exe to create a type safe DataSet.
Import this into your project.
load up data into your new type safe dataset from your DB and set that to be the reports datasource.

The below code then enables you to set the params

```
Private Sub foo()
  Dim parameterValues As New ParameterValues()
  parameterValues.Add("MyValue")
  MyDataSourceName.DataDefinition.ParameterFields("MyParamName").ApplyCurrentValues(parameterValues)
End Sub
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataTable completely same as data Set or if you are going to use data set the following code works without any problem.

ReportDocument cryRpt = new Rep

```
ortDocument();
Cls_Bl_CalibrationHeader clCalibrationHeader = new Cls_Bl_CalibrationHeader();
ParameterFieldDefinitions crParameterFieldDefinitions;
ParameterFieldDefinition crParameterFieldDefinition;
ParameterValues crParameterValues = new ParameterValues();
ParameterDiscreteValue crParameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
DataTable DT = null; 

reportPath = "\\Report.rpt";
cryRpt.Load(reportPath);

  DT = clClassName.M_GetByIDDate(sqlStr);                        
  cryRpt.SetDataSource(DT);
  DT = clClass.GetSubReportInfo();
  cryRpt.OpenSubreport("SubReport").SetDataSource(DT);

 crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = 1;
 crParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
 crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions["Parameter", "SubReport"];
 crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues.Clear();
 crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;
 crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue);
 crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues);  


crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
crystalReportViewer1.DisplayGroupTree = false;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

:D I faced with the same problem and then I found out that If you set DataSets to Subreports before main one it is ok then.